# Unknown type of macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros

I noticed something when looking the kind of language of a software (openFOAM) which is written in C++. It was something like,

```
field value;
```

For example,

```
temperature 25;
```

I wonder how this works. I mean how temperature is set to 25 without using equality sign. Any idea?

Comment: This is not C++.

Comment: Hm?  C++ only requires an equals sign because that's what the C++ spec says, but that doesn't mean the macro needs it.  The macro probably splits `field value;` over the semicolon to get the field/value pairs, and then splits again over the space to separate the field name from the value.

Comment: @Robert: C++ only requires an equals sign because that's what the spec says === C++ only requires an equals sign because C++ requires an equals sign :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: http://www.openfoam.org/docs/user/programming-language-OpenFOAM.php

Comment: @Lightness: And openFoam doesn't need it because the openFoam spec says it doesn't.

Comment: A programming language doesn't have to resemble a programming language it is implemented in.

Comment: @Shibli: Thanks for the link, but I already found that from Google. Perhaps you meant to direct it towards the OP? _[edit: oh, you **are** the OP. Then wha?]_

Comment: BTW, that's valid C++ too, if it follows (for example) `#define temperature attributes.T = `  Please don't do that, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because openFOAM has a parser that understands that format.

Such a parser is not hard to make, and C++ (with the help of a parser-generator tool like yacc, bison) is a popular choice for parsers because it can be very fast.

C++ is a Turing-complete language, therefore it can do anything that any other language can.  Specifically, it can process data that doesn't look like C++ code.

Comment: To be precise: C++ are two Turing-complete languages - don't forget Template Meta-Programming ;-)

Comment: @Andreas: I didn't, but C++ is a multiple paradigm language and I didn't want to start listing them all.  I believe that C++11 `constexpr` rules are also Turing complete.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages are typically context free. If the language is context free it can be parsed (I won't say it's trivial but it's a problem that has been solved so many times before and if you take a compilers class you'll have to do it for simple langauges).

The parser is simply looking for a declarations of the format `field value;`. It appears there is no type check happening so it is simply splitting on semi colon then on the space. Read about parsing context-free langauges, push down automata, and context free grammars if you're interested in learning about parsing source code.